# How to wrap c# attribute class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my unity editor scirpt(c#)

```
[MenuItem("Ro/Reimport All Editor Scripts %#i")]
static void St()
{
    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
}
```

I want to change it to:

```
[SetMenuItem("Ro/Reimport All Editor Scripts", "shortcut")]
static void St()
{
    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
}
```

But MenuItem is sealed class

```
public sealed class MenuItem : Attribute
```

How should I do that?

Comment: Is MenuItem from a third party library? You dont have access to the MenuItem Code?

Comment: You cannot derive from sealed classes and since it's Unity's built in class, you cannot do anything about that.

Comment: short answer : you can't. long answer : as you have noticed, you cannot inherit from a sealed class. you could wrap it in another class, but If you want to change the *behavior* of the attribute, you'd need to override or change more code used by the third party library or unity itself, (which you can't, and if you could would be a *lot* of work.)

Comment: Maybe you should look at what you are trying to achieve and find another method to ahieve it.

Comment: There's no point in deriving from an attribute. It's essentially a *marker* without runtime behaviour. Classes that understand the `MenuItem` marker wouldn't know how to deal with `SetMenuItem`. Classes read attributes through reflection. They know how to deal specifically with the type named `MenuItem` or the type whose name as a string is `MenuItem`. If you want to attach more info to the method, add a *different* attribute

Comment: *WHY* do you want this? The attribute already allows you to specify a shortcut. Why do you want to split the menuitem's definition? Did you encounter a problem specifying a shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because MenuItem is a sealed class.

I'm not that knowledgeable on Unity, so I checked the [MenuItem doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html); and I guess what you want to do is to have the shortcut separate from the menu item's name.

Which can't be done without modifying Unity's code itself, or reimplementing your own MenuItem class.